# Android Studio hint not auto hiding

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've accidentally changed pinned/floating mode settings on a hint window. Now, the hint appears but doesn't hide as it should. Here is the demonstration of the issue:

[image]

As seen on the GIF above, hint window displays correctly, but doesn't close when it should close. How can I make it behave normal? I've tried all the modes (docked, floating, pinned...) but none of them result in the behavior that I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quick documentation window is a bit unique. It can function as either a pop-up (the default) or a tool window. Right now you are in Tool Window mode. All the settings you talked about (float, dock, pinned, etc.) are tool window settings. What you want to do is restore it to pop-up mode clicking the red X in the tool bar of the window:

[image]

...or by using the "Quick Documentation" short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>⌃</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd> on a Mac.

Comment: Oh, thought it was a Close button. Yeah, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah... I think a different Icon would be good since the Red X typically means "Close". I've opened up a _Usability Problem_ report asking that the icon be changed: [IDEA-142007 Documentation window's "Restore Popup" button icon is misleading](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142007) Please consider voting for it.